# Get text between, but not including, header and footer using awk or sed

Tags: text, awk, sed, grep

Suppose I have a file myfile.txt, with the following contents:

```
1234
5678
start
stuff
stop
9871
```

I would like to get the data between the header 'start' and the footer 'stop' but **not** including these borders (so in this case, my result would just be the line 'stuff'). Using awk and sed, I tried the following:

```
 awk '/start/ { show=1 } show; /stop/ { show=0 }' myfile.txt
 sed -n '/start/,/stop/p' myfile.txt
```

But these include the header and footer in the output.  **How can I do it so that I don't retain the header and foot - but only the info in between?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just reverse the order of the tests:

```
$ awk '/stop/{show=0} show; /start/ { show=1 }' myfile.txt
stuff
```

#### How it works

- `/stop/{show=0}`

  Any time we encounter a line that matches the regex `stop`, we set the variable `show` to 0 (false).
- `show;`

  If `show` is true, print the line.

  In more detail, `show` is a *condition*, meaning that it is evaluated and, if true, an action is performed.  Since we don't explicitly specify an action, the default action is performed which is `print $0`.

  Since no action is explicitly specified, we need to follow `show` with `;` in order to separated it from the next command.
- `/start/ { show=1 }`

  Any time we encounter a line that matches the regex `start`, we set the variable `show` to 1 (true).

Comment: Great stuff! I was just aware of `awk '/regex1/,/regex2/' file` which includes regex1 and regex2. Could you give a little explanation why `awk '/regex2/ {var=0} var ; /regex1/ {var=1}' file` takes different addresses, needs a variable and use a `;` instead of a `,`?

Comment: @JohnGoofy I just added an explanation to the answer.  The construct `/regex1/,/regex2/` is a _range_ and, as you point, a _range_ doesn't solve this particular problem.  Consequently, we need to do something different entirely.

Comment: Well done! This is very well explaint! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With gnu sed

```
sed '/start/,/stop/!d;//d' myfile.txt
```

Comment: I get `bash: !d: event not found` when entering that in the bash. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @userunknown you are right, i get a problem with your echo, not the same. It's ok with your echo like that echo "1234 ...9871" |\ my sed on another line. Or use echo -e "1234\n5678\n... or use printf '%s\n' "1234" "5678" .... I think it's a echo issue but i'm not sure.

Comment: @userunknown perhaps you are not quoting the sed instruction or using double quotes instead of single quotes i.e. bash is interpolating the sed commands.

Comment: I tried like you, with sed '...' FILE, and that works.

Answer (score 1):

Another sed-command, but gnu-sed, too:

```
echo "1234
5678
start
stuff
stop
9871" | sed -n '/start/,/stop/p' | sed '1d;$d' 
stuff
```

There is no problem in programming, which couldn't be solved with another layer of sed. :)

Comment: If there is 2 groups of start and stop, you get a wrong result.

Comment: @ctac: Well, there was no hint, that there could be more than one such section. What to do, if the second starts, before the first ends? If there is an ending pattern before the start or a second start? before stop?